# OrientDB Select query instead of join

Tags: orientdb

I have an OrientDB document database. I executed the following commands via Studio:

```
DROP CLASS student;
DROP CLASS studyCourse;

CREATE CLASS student;
CREATE CLASS studyCourse;

CREATE PROPERTY student.Id INTEGER;
CREATE INDEX Student.Id UNIQUE;
CREATE PROPERTY student.surname STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY student.FK_studyCourse_abbreviation STRING;

CREATE PROPERTY studyCourse.abbreviation STRING;
CREATE INDEX studyCourse.abbreviation UNIQUE;
CREATE PROPERTY studyCourse.name STRING;

CREATE LINK student TYPE LINKSET FROM student.FK_studyCourse_abbreviation TO studyCourse.abbreviation INVERSE;

INSERT INTO studyCourse SET abbreviation = 'Inf', name = 'informatics';

INSERT INTO student SET Id = '11111', surname = 'Miller';
UPDATE studyCourse ADD student = (SELECT FROM student WHERE Id = '11111') WHERE abbreviation = 'Inf';
```

Now I want to select values as described in the manual ( http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL.html ):

```
SELECT * FROM studyCourse WHERE student.surname = 'Miller';
```

There are no records found.

Comment: What version of OrientDb are you using ?

Comment: I am using orientdb-community-2.1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using *contains* instead of *=*

```
SELECT FROM studyCourse WHERE student.surname contains 'Miller'
```

this is working for me:

```
----+-----+-----------+------------+-----------+-------
#   |@RID |@CLASS     |abbreviation|name       |student
----+-----+-----------+------------+-----------+-------
0   |#14:0|studyCourse|Inf         |informatics|[1]    
----+-----+-----------+------------+-----------+-------
```

Ivan